# Call to a member function result() on boolean

Tags: php, codeigniter, web-hosting

its working on localhost
but when i put it on free hosting, im getting the error

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>
> Type: Error
>
> Message: Call to a member function result() on boolean
>
> Filename:
>   /storage/ssd1/658/11801658/public_html/application/models/M_relasi.php

is the hosting maybe related to it?

to put it simply
my controller

```
public function hitung()
  {               
    $RELASI = $this->m_relasi->tampil();           
    $data['relasi'] = array();

    foreach ($RELASI as $row) {
      $data['relasi'][$row->kd_gejala][] = $row->kd_penyakit;
    }

    $this->load->view('hasildiagnosa2',$data);     
  }
```

my model

```
public function tampil()
{
   return $this->db->get('tb_relasi')->result();
}
```

my view

```
<?php
    $GEJALA = $gejala;
    $DIAGNOSA = $diagnosa;
    $hasil[] = array(
    'arr' => array_keys($DIAGNOSA),
    'name' => implode(',', array_keys($DIAGNOSA)),
    'value' => 1,
    );

    foreach ($selected as $kode):
    $new_hasil = array();
    $arr_diagnosa = $relasi[$kode];
?>

<?php foreach($hasil as $row):
  $arr = array_intersect($row['arr'], $arr_diagnosa);
  $name =  implode(',', $arr);
  $value = $row['value'] * $GEJALA[$kode]->bobot;
  $new_hasil[] = array(
    'arr' => $arr,
    'name' => $name,
    'value' => $value,
  );

  $arr2 = array_intersect($row['arr'], array_keys($DIAGNOSA));
  $name2 =  implode(',', $arr2);
  $value2 = $row['value'] * (1 - $GEJALA[$kode]->bobot);

  $new_hasil[] = array(
    'arr' => $arr2,
    'name' => $name2,
    'value' => $value2,
  );

  $hasil = $new_hasil;
  $hasil_akhir = $new_hasil; 
<?php endforeach;?>

<?php
$unik = array();
foreach($hasil as $row){
$unik[$row['name']] = $row['arr'];
}
$new_hasil = DS_hitung($unik, $hasil);
$hasil = $new_hasil;
?>
<?php endforeach;

$best = DS_get_best($hasil);
$diags = array();
foreach($best['arr'] as $val){
  $diags[] =  $DIAGNOSA[$val];
  $diagnosa_akhir = $DIAGNOSA[$val];
  $ket_diag = $keterangan[$val];
}
<?php endforeach;
```

Comment: Most likely the connection to the database failed in your hosting environment.